# fs.createReadStream vs Readable for heavy files

Tags: javascript, node.js

Are there any differences between `createReadStream` from `fs` and `Readable` from `stream`

test.csv

```
name,color
audi,green
bmw,red
mercedes,silver
```

fs.createReadStream

```
import { createReadStream } from 'fs'
import parser from 'csv-parser'

;(async () => {
  createReadStream('test.csv')
    .pipe(parser())
    .on('data', (data) => console.log(data))
})()
```

Readable

```
import { readFile } from 'fs/promises'
import { Readable } from 'stream'
import parser from 'csv-parser'

;(async () => { 
 const csv = await readFile('test.csv')
 
 Readable.from(csv)
    .pipe(parser())
    .on('data', (data) => console.log(data))
})()
```

Both seem to do the same thing. but which one is more efficient for a heavy volume of data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fs.readFile`/`fsPromises.readFile` read the entire contents of the file at once, whereas `createReadStream` only reads chunks at a time. Using `readFile` with `Readable.from` may provide the same API, but by reading the entire contents to memory, you lose the benefits of streaming.

If you're reading heavy files, I would recommend `createReadStream` over `readFile` as you can start processing and parsing the data without having to wait for the entire file to be read, and you don't even need to read the entire file into memory (unless your use case requires it, that is). If your files are small, it probably doesn't matter (but do [profile it](https://medium.com/@paul_irish/debugging-node-js-nightlies-with-chrome-devtools-7c4a1b95ae27)).

Comment: Thanks, the thing is that I actually need to wait till the whole file is finished, then I use on end. I found that when I was using csvtojson and the csv is 410mb it fails, but not with either of this methods

Answer (score 1):

The main point of using steam API is to optimize memory usage. If you just `const csv = await readFile('test.csv')` then the content of the whole file is already read and saved into memory.

The way you use `Readable.from` only wrap the csv content into a readable stream interface. But the memory is already allocated. So it does not help improve performance at all.

On the other side, `createReadStream('test.csv')` creates a "real" readable stream. It’s driven by downstream consumers and only read small chunks of data on demand.

So definitely use `fs.createReadStream`